# Ugly popups on beta sites

Tags: discussion, design, beta-sites

I was using a beta site and I noticed how ugly the popup notices are on there. Unlike the notices on non-beta sites, I feel like I'm stuck 5-10 years ago in windows XP or earlier. Why don't these look more like the standard ones on the other sites? Both are shown below.

[image: pretty popup] (non-beta) (Game developers)
[image: ugly popup](beta)

Comment: Clearly the popups are in beta as well.  It doesn't get pretty until Jin comes along.  Focus on content first.

Comment: but the popups on StackOverflow, SuperUser, Game Devs, etc. all look pretty much the same, other than font and color -- couldn't there be some sort of default that is generic but doesn't look like it came from 2000?

Comment: There is a default on betas you just don't like it. I do like it, actually, but in any case the beta sites are not *supposed* to look finished: they might go away it they don't do well.

Comment: I like the rest of the look; I just feel like it might be pushing people away. Maybe just me being overly sensitive - I wanted to see what others think.

Comment: Next time, tag as [design]. Otherwise Jin won't notice :)

Comment: I personally prefer the pop-ups shown on beta sites.